# Spring Boot Saving/Reading entities running out of connections

Tags: spring-boot, hibernate

I am relatively inexperienced in using Java Spring/Hibernate. This problem may be easy to solve, but I feel like I have done hours of error look ups at this point. Here are some overall specs of my program: Using h2 database, database is locally stored, using spring-boot-starter,  spring-boot-security.

**Problem**
I am trying to create an online Wiki. So far, I have not had any hiccups. I am able to save, update, and delete entities (which are called WikiPages). However, I noticed that if I try to read/save/update/delete a WikiPage around 5 times, the application is no longer able to communicate with my locally stored h2 server, the program hangs, and I am unable to view any webpages at all. I did not encounter this problem on my previous project which has a very similar DAO.

I have a suspicion that there is some sort of problem with my DAO interacting with the database. Any help would be appreciated. Please let me know if you would like to see a different file in the program. I enabled debug console logging

**Application Properties**

```
spring.datasource.url = jdbc:h2:tcp://localhost/~/Downloads/Data/Database
spring.datasource.driverClassName=org.h2.Driver
spring.datasource.username=sa
spring.datasource.password=
spring.jpa.database-platform=org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=none
spring.h2.console.enabled=true

server.error.include-message=always

server.port=80

logging.level.org.springframework.web=DEBUG
logging.level.org.hibernate=ERROR
```

**WikiPage**

```
package com.costi.csw9.Model;

import lombok.EqualsAndHashCode;
import lombok.Getter;
import lombok.NoArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Setter;

import javax.persistence.*;
import java.time.LocalDateTime;

@Getter
@Setter
@EqualsAndHashCode
@NoArgsConstructor
@Entity
public class WikiPage {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id", nullable = false)
    private Long id;
    @Column(nullable = false, unique = true)
    private String title;
    @Column(nullable = false)
    private LocalDateTime lastEdited;
    @Column(nullable = false)
    private String subtitle;

    private boolean enabled = false;
    private String category;
    @Column(columnDefinition="text")
    private String body;

    @OneToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "user_id")
    private User author;

    public WikiPage(String title, String subtitle, User author, String category, String body) {
        this.title = title;
        this.subtitle = subtitle;
        this.author = author;
        this.category = category;
        this.body = body;
    }

    public WikiPage(User author){
        this.author = author;
    }

}
```

**WikiDaoImpl**

```
    package com.costi.csw9.Repository;
    
    import com.costi.csw9.Model.User;
    import com.costi.csw9.Model.UserRole;
    import com.costi.csw9.Model.WikiCategory;
    import com.costi.csw9.Model.WikiPage;
    import org.hibernate.Criteria;
    import org.hibernate.Session;
    import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
    import org.hibernate.criterion.Restrictions;
    import org.hibernate.query.Query;
    import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
    import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;
    
    import javax.persistence.TypedQuery;
    import javax.persistence.criteria.CriteriaBuilder;
    import javax.persistence.criteria.CriteriaQuery;
    import javax.persistence.criteria.Root;
    import java.time.LocalDateTime;
    import java.util.List;
    
    @Repository
    public class WikiDaoImpl implements WikiRepository{
        @Autowired
        private SessionFactory sessionFactory;
    
        @Override
        public WikiPage findById(Long id) {
            Session session = sessionFactory.openSession();
            WikiPage wikiPage = session.get(WikiPage.class, id);
            session.close();
            return wikiPage;
        }
    
        @Override
        public List<WikiPage> findByCategory(WikiCategory category) {
            Session session = sessionFactory.openSession();
    
            CriteriaBuilder cb = session.getCriteriaBuilder();
            CriteriaQuery<WikiPage> cr = cb.createQuery(WikiPage.class);
            Root<WikiPage> root = cr.from(WikiPage.class);
            cr.select(root);
    
            cr.select(root).where(cb.like(root.get("category"), category.name()));
    
            Query<WikiPage> query = session.createQuery(cr);
            List<WikiPage> results = query.getResultList();
            
            return results;
        }
    
        @Override
        public List<WikiPage> getByApproval(boolean enabled) {
            Session session = sessionFactory.openSession();
    
            CriteriaBuilder cb = session.getCriteriaBuilder();
            CriteriaQuery<WikiPage> cr = cb.createQuery(WikiPage.class);
            Root<WikiPage> root = cr.from(WikiPage.class);
            cr.select(root);
    
            if(enabled){
                cr.select(root).where(cb.isTrue(root.get("enabled")));
            }else{
                cr.select(root).where(cb.isFalse(root.get("enabled")));
            }
    
            Query<WikiPage> query = session.createQuery(cr);
            List<WikiPage> results = query.getResultList();
    
            return results;
        }
    
        @Override
        public List<WikiPage> findAll() {
            // Open a session
            Session session = sessionFactory.openSession();
    
            // Get all people with a Hibernate criteria
            List<WikiPage> all = session.createCriteria(WikiPage.class).list();
    
            // Close session
            session.close();
    
            return all;
        }
    
        @Override
        public void save(WikiPage wikiPage) {
            //Add in last edited
            wikiPage.setLastEdited(LocalDateTime.now());
    
            // Open a session
            Session session = sessionFactory.openSession();
    
            // Begin a transaction
            session.beginTransaction();
    
            // Save the person
            session.saveOrUpdate(wikiPage);
    
            // Commit the transaction
            session.getTransaction().commit();
    
            // Close the session
            session.close();
        }
    
        @Override
        public void delete(WikiPage wikiPage) {
            // Open the session
            Session session = sessionFactory.openSession();
    
            // Not completley sure why I have to do this, but I need to find the page via id in this function
            WikiPage page = session.get(WikiPage.class, wikiPage.getId());
    
            // Begin translation
            session.beginTransaction();
    
            // Delete Page
            session.delete(page);
    
            // Commit the transaction
            session.getTransaction().commit();
    
            // Close the session
            session.close();
        }
    }
```

**Error**

```
2022-06-28 20:35:22.933 DEBUG 10820 --- [p-nio-80-exec-4] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : "ERROR" dispatch for GET "/error", parameters={}
2022-06-28 20:35:22.934 DEBUG 10820 --- [p-nio-80-exec-4] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped to org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.servlet.error.BasicErrorController#errorHtml(HttpServletRequest, HttpServletResponse)
2022-06-28 20:35:22.935 DEBUG 10820 --- [p-nio-80-exec-4] o.s.w.s.v.ContentNegotiatingViewResolver : Selected 'text/html' given [text/html, text/html;q=0.8]
2022-06-28 20:35:22.935 DEBUG 10820 --- [p-nio-80-exec-4] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Exiting from "ERROR" dispatch, status 500
```

Answer (score 0):

although I did not find what I did wrong in my code. I eventually go it to work with some light testing by turning as many DAO methods into JPA queries as I can. Hope this helps others!